# TikZ: How can I remove the undesired border of a polygon with color gradient?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, border, gradient

folks!

I want to draw a polygon with TikZ that has a color gradient from white to gray. Unfortunately, the polygon has a small gray border and I don't know why and how to remove it. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikz{\path[fill, left color=white, right color=black!10] (0, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (1, 3) -- (0, 4) -- cycle;}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: MWE]

You can see the border which seems to be in the color `black!10` (notably the left, top and bottom border). If I set the color of the border explicitly to white (`draw=white`) it looks fine but only on white background (of course). In my image, the left part of the polygon is on a white background the right part of a gray (`black!10`) background. Thus, a white border is not the solution that works for me.

So, the question is: **How can I remove the border?** (And: What is the reason that the border even exists?) Or, in case it is not possible: How can I set the left border to `white` and the right border to `black!10`?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Cornelius

Comment: As you accepted the answer, you can also upvote it.

Comment: @Tarass: I actually did this already. Due to the lack of reputation it is recorded but not publicity displayed, StackExchange said. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. Welcome to Latex.SX !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you see is not a "real" border but rather a filled area, that is additionally shaded. Replace `fill` by `shade` to only shade it.

Comment: That's it! Easy like that! It even works if I remove `fill` at all.